# Javascript Regex: Strip path until last occurence in a capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex, path, strip

I'm trying to filter a path in the first capturing group.

Currently the first capturing group extracts the path including its parent paths.

While this behavior is completely fine, I don't want the path itself to be included. Capture group one should only extract the parent paths if any.

Capture group 2 must stay as is. (See the red numbers in picture below)

**Regex:**

```
/^(?:music|pictures)\/tom((?:\/((?:[\w-]+(?:[ ]+[\w-]+)*)))*)$/gm
```

---

**Match against:**

```
music/tom/foldername
music/tom/folder name
music/tom/foldername/folder2
```

---

**Expected results:**

[image]

> **[MATCH 1]** 
>   I expect the first match (green) to be empty, since it
>   does not have any parents nor childs
>
> **[MATCH 2]** the same as [MATCH 1]
>
> **[MATCH 3]** I expect the first match (green) to only contain the
>   parents

---

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yN2kK2/1

---

Technically I could just keep my regex and use Javascript for the expected behavior:

`str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/'))`

However, I appreciate if this could be archived with the regex as well.

Comment: something like **[`this`](https://regex101.com/r/yN2kK2/2)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your regex to achieve desired behavior like

```
^(?:music|pictures)\/tom(\/(?:[\w-]+(?:[ ]+[\w-]+)*))*(\/(?:[\w-]+(?:[ ]+[\w-]+)*))$
                        <--------------------------->
                        Captures the parent directory
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN2kK2/2)**

If you consider everything after `/tom` (and just before last) as parent directory, you can modify the regex as

```
^(?:music|pictures)\/tom((?:\/(?:[\w-]+(?:[ ]+[\w-]+)*))*)(\/(?:[\w-]+(?:[ ]+[\w-]+)*))$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN2kK2/3)**

Comment: Splendid work @rock321987. Thank you very much, yet once again for your outstanding help here at Stackoverflow. By looking at your regex description above and the explanation on regex101.com, it makes sense to me now.